# Has Wolverine ever practiced solo vigilantism?

Tags: marvel, wolverine, spider-man

I know this question is a bit subtle, but let me elaborate it.

In all the canons I have read or seen, Spider-Man swings over the city and whenever wherever he sees the smallest of crimes happening or a person in trouble, he jumps into the situation to save them, be it a jaywalker on the street about to be hit by a vehicle, a mugging taking place in a dark alley, small robberies, etc.

But from what I have seen or read about Wolverine, he is most of the time associated with a team. So basically, he undertakes the missions of that team under the orders of a leader.

In other cases, trouble comes searching for him. He gets involved in action, adventure or fights which directly affect him or people close to him.

In yet other cases, Wolverine has jumped into the situation to help the victim because the victim had once helped Wolverine in some way or other. He just goes back to repay him/her.

In one case, in The Ultimate Spiderman animated series, Wolverine is chasing Sabretooth or something like that. During this, he comes across Spider-Man trying to help people hypnotized by some bad guy with hypnotic orb on his forehead. So he just jumps in the situation to help Spidey and save the day. But basically, he never found the problem himself: it was coincidence that while undertaking his personal mission, he came across it.

I have never read or seen any incident where Wolverine himself goes around randomly to find and fight bad guys or to help innocent people.

Are there any such events in the Marvel universe?

Comment: Wolverine is fighting evil of his own free will unless he's being coerced or controlled. Even if he has orders, he's *choosing* to follow them. I don't think anyone doubts that he'd refuse to follow orders he didn't agree with. What you really seem to be asking is whether or not Wolverine practices solo **vigilantism**.

Comment: @CreationEdge: Yes

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri: then why did you give your question a title that doesn’t actually describe what you’re asking?

Comment: There you go, much better. So you’re asking whether Wolverine has ever *patrolled*, like Spider-Man does. (I’m not sure if *any* of the X-Men do this, let alone a grumpy loner like Wolverine, but I’m far from an X-Pert.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Perhaps _that_ should be in the title (patrolling).

Comment: @SQB: eh, maybe. The question is a slightly tricky one to understand, so I think a vaguer title might help.

Comment: Wolverine is a soldier; soldiers learn early on not to look for trouble, and never volunteer for anything. He's been drafted, coerced, guilt-tripped, and persuaded but I don't think he's ever been shown volunteering for anything. When left to live as he liked, he chose to get a job and settle down with someone, not go out looking for bad guys.

Comment: I'd be interested to see an instance in which Wolverine stops a petty crime like Spidey would, since it's hard to believe he'd even think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: No, Wolverine does not usually undertake street-level vigilantism like Spider-Man.**

---

Despite his loner attitude, [**Wolverine**](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Howlett_(Earth-616)) (as a rule) does not typically undertake the sort of street-level vigilantism you describe. Unlike [Daredevil](http://marvel.wikia.com/Matthew_Murdock_(Earth-616)) or [Spider-Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/Peter_Parker_(Earth-616)), Wolverine does not maintain a "territory" that he then patrols and protects. Instead, Wolverine is more like a soldier - he either goes where he is sent or he deals with trouble as it comes to him.

That said, however, there IS one time in his life when he acted as a street vigilante. During his time in [**Madripoor**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Madripoor), Logan would often grow bored and traverse the seedier parts of Madripoor looking for excitement. More often than not, that excitement would be rescuing tourists or the defenseless from attack by common street thugs - a nightly occurrence in [Lowtown](http://marvel.wikia.com/Lowtown). He did not wear his Wolverine uniform during this time, as the world at large believed that the [X-Men](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men_(Earth-616)) - including Wolverine - were dead. Instead, he often wore dark-colored "sneaking clothes" or street clothes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a question where it's hard to prove a negative, I think it can be safely said that Wolverine has not gone out to proactively seek random crime without evidence that said crime was happening. In any media.